# Non UWP media player

Tags: windows, media-player

I'm searching for a media player that is no UWP app like *Microsoft Movies & TV*. But it has to integrate the [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols?view=winrt-19041), so when you increase/decrease the volume you see the media metadata. Spotify and all browsers I use (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) do integrate them so it's not UWP specific.

But VLC, 5kPlayer, ... do not

Comment: May I ask what the reason to be non-UWP is?

Comment: Because UWP makes a lot of problems when I'm trying to control the window, because of fake HWNDs, ... So I need a media player that's not based on UWP